# AWS Elastic IP is not working properly with the android app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I have a demo server which is working fine web page and app both but it is running on public IP which will change after restart. I have to use IP to open portal as web page and in android application. Whenever i try to assign Elastic IP to the server, Elastic IP didn't working properly. Webpage is working fine but app is not working with Elastic IP.

App is working fine with default public IP, but not with Elastic IP.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it "didn't work properly"?  What do you try to do, and what error / unexpected behaviour do you get?

Comment: Do you connect to the instance directly or use ELB?

Answer (score 1):

Check the security group assigned especially inbound ports opened.